# start process in windows 8 metro application

Tags: process, microsoft-metro

how can i start a process like rasphone.exe by code in windows 8 metro application?
there is System.Diagnostics.Process but the System.Diagnostics in metro application doesn't contain process

Comment: Please mark as answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the Metro-style applications work in the highly sandboxed environment and there is no way to directly start an external application.

You can try to use [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241801.aspx) class – depends on your need it may provide you a feasible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Carl's answer is right. You could use a trick though: Create a normal .NET application without UI that gets the name of an executable passed in a file with a dedicated extension (like .launcher). This application would launch the application that is passed via the Process class. In Windows 8 the dedicated extension must be associated with the launcher application. That unfortunately must be done by hand (or maybe using a small setup application the user has to execute).

In the Windows Store App you can then create a .launcher file with the path to the executable and launch this via the Launcher class.