# C# get windows 8 start/metro process

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to get windows 8 start/metro process?
If it is, than how?

I tried to list all the running process but I cant figure which is the start
If you ask what do I need it for > I need to because I want to put it permanently on one of my screens without being minimized / closed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Start Screen, like the Start Menu in older versions, is part of Explorer.  I'm fairly certain you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Based on that, the only solution I can think of right now is to make program which will simulate the metro... (like Classic Shell Menu for old start menu)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT!!

There are two ways to I know about to launch apps. You can launch apps through FA(file association) or through PH (protocol handlers) (Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync and Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync)

I answered this a couple of days ago. But I not all is mentioned in my answer.

> All the Metro-style applications work in the highly sandboxed
>   environment and there is no way to directly start an external
>   application.
>
> You can try to [use Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241801.aspx) class – depends on your need it may
>   provide you a feasible solution.

Check [the original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734315/start-process-in-windows-8-metro-application/13734520#13734520)!

Comment: Opps I may have misread the question.. anyway.. THe launcher class may be of help for you.