# Is there a possibility to start another App or Program from a Windows 8 Store App (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to start another App or Program from my Windows Store App. For example my App is showing emails, so if someone clicks on such an email Outlook should open. Is this possible in an "App-Sandbox"?

Comment: "Is this possible in an "App-Sandbox"?" - let's hope not.

Comment: Did you try anything? Some code example with your effort would be nice. Please read [help]

Comment: try this stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734315/start-process-in-windows-8-metro-application

Comment: @Gusdor The Launcher class does not work in my case.

Comment: @SonerGönül Tried the Launcher class but with no success. Also tried to save a *.lnk file in my app directory (where my app has full access) and launch this file. Also not successful

Comment: @MitchWheat you are right. But my client wants it so i had to find a possibilty ;). The M$ App can also do things which are "not possible" for "normal" developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to just launch an arbitrary application, but with custom protocol activation you can launch an app that handles that protocol and if it is not installed - the OS will ask the user to install it. It means that if you can define a custom protocol in your app - you can launch it from another app with this protocol assuming no other app registers to handle it. An example of that is any XBOX Live app - if you check their manifest files - they all handle custom protocols.

If your specific question is about launching a specific app by name or location then no, this is not possible, but if you know a protocol handled by the app you want to launch - you can try using that - just bear in mind that there might be other apps that handle that protocol.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for this detailed answer. I have to research the way of custom protocols. there might be no other apps that handle the protocol because it is an enterprise environment ;)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, it's not possible.

You can open files with their associated application but not spawn any arbitrary external process.

As @mitch-wheat pointed out, that's why it's called a sandbox.

Comment: Does not make me confident but I think I have to live with this fact. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec)

The sample is for Windows 8.1 but I think will work for Windows 8 as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is a misunderstanding. I do not have a file to open. Ok if I have an email there is a file but the meaning of my question was a little bit different. I want to open word, calc or excel f.e. if i click a button in my app, with no file workarounds