# How to run external executable using JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

How to run external executable using JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8?

Im creating Windows 8 app, and need it to run exeternal applications like: notepad.exe

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad news but this does not work, not in C# and not in JavaScript.
You can not break an App sandbox. [Posted this question some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969019/is-there-a-possibility-to-start-another-app-or-program-from-a-windows-8-store-ap)

Comment: No problem as you see I had the same problem ... with no solution at all. A positiv answer or possiblitiy will be better for both of us :)