# How to run .exe file from windows 8.1 store app?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5, windows-8.1

I am developing a windows 8.1 store app and also, I have made an executable file for a matlab code.Now, is it possible to run an exe file from the app say for example when I press a button then it should start the executable? I have already searched on google and a lot of solutions are available for running an exe file using c# but I couldn't find anywhere how to run it from the app.

Comment: Where exactly are you failing at? What is the problem, do you get an error message? The .exe for matlab code is a console application, or does it have a gui? Does it need any arguments? Still, did you look at : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start and System.Diagnostics.Process.StartInfo

Comment: The .exe file is GUI based program, and Process is not available in windows 8.1 store app

Comment: Oh boy, I missed the "store app" part, tried it briefly and failed hard, ... Then searched and probably the only helpful thing to be found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969019   where the unpleasing answer to your question is you can not do that.

Comment: This is not possible, Store apps run in a sandbox that defeat any attempts to do this.  A strong malware countermeasure.  Trying to use local-loopback across a socket will not work either, the only external process they can talk to is one that runs off-site on a server.  Targeting Store is just not the appropriate choice if you want to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility to start another App or Program from a Windows 8 Store App (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969019/is-there-a-possibility-to-start-another-app-or-program-from-a-windows-8-store-ap)

Comment: You can open files for reading/writing if they reside in the application's temporary folder, perhaps you can try to place your executable there see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

As store apps run in sandbox mode so you can't launch file types that contain code or script if they are executed automatically by the operating system, such as, .exe, .msi, and .js files. This restriction protects users from potentially malicious files that could modify the operating system. You can use this method to launch file types that can contain script if they are executed by an app that isolates the script, such as, .docx files. Apps like Microsoft Word keep the script in .docx files from modifying the operating system.

you can see more details about it from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299102.aspx).