# Windows 8 Kiosk Mode - Launcher App for multiple Apps in Kiosk mode

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, kiosk, kiosk-mode

In Windows 8 kiosk mode, we can set a launcher that App that gets launched at loggin time. However if we have to provide access to a set of Apps in Kiosk mode, I could not find a way.

Hence I wish to develop a windows 8 App which would be the container or placeholder for launching my own Apps. My requirement is that in the Windows 8 Kiosk mode we want to launch a Windows 8 App that would be container for launching other Windows 8 Apps.

So as an example, I want to develop a Windows 8 App - Enterprise Application Launcher. This App would have a tile for other Apps in the enterprise like Customer Relationship App, Leave Application App etc. When the user enters the Windows 8 in Kiosk mode the Enterprise Application launcher would be launched. From the user can launch other Apps.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969019/is-there-a-possibility-to-start-another-app-or-program-from-a-windows-8-store-ap

Answer (score 0):

Try this example from MSDN
[link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec)

You can also look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969019/is-there-a-possibility-to-start-another-app-or-program-from-a-windows-8-store-ap)

Comment: Thanks. From my investigation so fare, in the Kiosk mode this is not allowed to launch another App in any way.