# How to bundle and install an exe app with window store app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a windows store app but i want to install another exe file when the metro app installs. It is because i need to use some features that are not accessible via metro applications. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying *you* are trying to do anything wrong, but even with bundling, there is **no way** Microsoft would let you actually install/run an exe.

It wouldn't work on ARM devices, and is an absolutely **ENORMOUS** security hole. Windows 8 apps are run in a sandbox, and that sandbox is restricted to very specific operations (you can't even mess with the power saving settings!). Running an exe file is just not going to happen.

See [Is there a possibility to start another App or Program from a Windows 8 Store App (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969019/is-there-a-possibility-to-start-another-app-or-program-from-a-windows-8-store-ap) for more information

Comment: Well, I could imagine someone not caring about running on ARM. I would love to be able to sell the desktop tool app I'm currently working on through the store even if it would only run on the couple of hundred millions of desktop PCs out there. :)

Comment: @FilipSkakun The problem is that windows store for ARM is no different than that for Intel. I agree that people would take advantage of it given the choice by Microsoft. Even the desktop apps that are "in" the store just link to the vendors website for standard purchase. My point was that there is no choice, you have to deal with the setup created by MS.

Comment: I think you used to be able to publish an app without an ARM build. I would assume that it doesn't show up if you are running on an ARM tablet, no?

Comment: @FilipSkakun Maybe, I've not seen the option when building, but from the documentation it looks like such an option *could* exist. Regardless, the other security features make this feature impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could ask the user to save and run the exe?
I'm wondering though if "Microsoft" would allow you to package an exe with the app that isn't part of the app.
I'm also curious - how would you do the communication between the two apps if it is at all needed? I think there are no supported process communication APIs. Would you use some sort of a mail box file/folder?

Comment: I'm guessing they would allow it as part of the build process. The problem is that there wouldn't be a way to *execute* it. The comms would be an issue (though a lesser one) as you have noted.

Comment: Well, you can ask the user to go and run this app from the specified location.

Comment: Your app installs into a hard-to-reach location. You *could* ask the user to go and run it assuming they were on the Pro OS, though most wouldn't bother finding it if I had to guess.

Comment: The user would be offered to select a folder to save a copy of the file first. If this offered a feature they would really want - they might consider it.

Comment: That would require the app to have access to the local filesystem in order to put it there. You get access to *some* of the filesystem (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx ) but not *all* of it. So yes, that could work, but its still a big pain.

Comment: You can get access to almost any location if the user picks it using a [picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx). Besides, you could just package an installer exe and ask user to put it on say the desktop and then run it.

Comment: Got to love incomplete documentation. Nice find! Yes, the user could select the Desktop and tell your program to copy the "bundled" exe file with it. Still ridiculously impractical, and not remotely automatic, but possible. Thanks for the information!