# How to launch a desktop application from windows store apps?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

Please tell me how we can launch a desktop application or .exe file from a Windows store app using c#.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How about `Process.Start`?

Comment: It's not impossible. And question looks like duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969019/is-there-a-possibility-to-start-another-app-or-program-from-a-windows-8-store-ap

Comment: @Herdo This namespace is not available in Windows Store Apps

Comment: @feeeper You mean its not possible to call an external program from Windows Store app?

Comment: @WaqasAhmedKhan yes. Becouse windows store application in sand-boxed environment run.

Comment: @WaqasAhmedKhan Ah yeah. Welcome to the sandbox. ^^ The windows app sandbox doesn't allow to start files containing executeable code (.exe, .msi, .js). However, you can use a file-extension associated start.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, you can't directly launch an executable from a Windows Store App because of the sandboxed environment. However, you can use the [launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcher.aspx) API to start an executable associated with a file. Therefore, you could create a file association between a custom file extension and the application you want to launch. Then, just use the launcher API to open a file having the custom file extension.

```
public async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Path to the file in the app package to launch
   string imageFile = @"images\test.png";

   var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);

   if (file != null)
   {
      // Launch the retrieved file
      var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

      if (success)
      {
         // File launched
      }
      else
      {
         // File launch failed
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Could not find file
   }
}
```