# How can I open the application folder in the Windows 8 file explorer without the Process class?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I have a Windows 8 application created in C# with XAML and in the settings charm for the application I have added a button.

The purpose of this button is to open the application's folder in the Windows 8 file explorer.

In a normal C# app I would have used:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path/to/folder");
```

However `System.Diagnostics` does not contain the `Process` object.

Can anyone recommend a workaround for this issue?

Comment: This is sort of tangential question, but why doesn't `Process` exist in the `System.Diganostics` framework? Isn't that a part of .NET?

Comment: Seems like the same question as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734315/start-process-in-windows-8-metro-application  Have you tried using `Windows.System.Launcher` ?

Comment: @JeffBridgman, the short answer is that Windows Store Application can only use subset of "full" .NET. See, for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441592.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(folder);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn889617.aspx