# How do you launch speech recognition on a button click in a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, speech-recognition, speech

I have recently discovered the ability to [use speech recognition](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/using-speech-recognition) in Windows 8.1. I was wondering how I could, perhaps, on a button click at least launch this application in my Windows Store app to be able to enable speech to text for a user. I am not currently sure of a way to do this, but after doing some digging I read that [I might be able to use the Launcher class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734315/start-process-in-windows-8-metro-application) to launch a Uri to the link for speech recognition. So far I have been unsuccessful. Please, if anyone knows how this can be accomplished, it would be of great value to me.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private async void LaunchSpeechRecognition(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibility\Speech Recognition.lnk"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Speech recognition is a desktop app. WinRT (Windows Store) apps can't invoke such apps using `Launcher` class. `Launcher` class is used to launch files (.lnk files are shortcut which is ultimately a desktop app) & limited set of URIs. Those URIs are WinRT app specific or HTTP, FTP, [custom protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779672.aspx), etc.

[Walkthrough: using Windows 8 Custom Protocol Activation](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-using-windows-8-custom.html)

Comment: Are you sure there's no way around this, such as launching a webpage which links to the application somehow?

Comment: You can launch Internet webpage using `LaunchUriAsync(...)`.

Comment: Do you know what the limitations are on Windows RT if you do that? For example, can I launch a webpage that downloads a link the user can then launch on their machines?